# How to create Sprites with label in Quintus.js?

Tags: javascript, string, sprite, game-engine

I want to create a typing game, so my sprites need to be generated in run time, with "labels". a String become a sprite to be typed. Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert a `Q.UI.Text` object into a sprite like this:

```
var Q = Quintus()
        .include('Sprites, Scenes, UI')
        .setup({ maximize: true })

Q.Sprite.extend('LabelSprite', {
    init: function(p) {
        this._super(p, {text: 'default text'});
    }
});

Q.scene("level1",function(stage) {
    var label_sprite = stage.insert(new Q.LabelSprite({
        x: 150,
        y: 50,
        label_text: 'label-text in a sprite',
        label_text_color: 'grey',
        label_offset_x: 0,
        label_offset_y: 0
    }));

    var label = stage.insert(new Q.UI.Text({                
        label: label_sprite.p.label_text,
        color: label_sprite.p.label_text_color,
        x: label_sprite.p.label_offset_x,
        y: label_sprite.p.label_offset_y
    }), label_sprite);
});

Q.stageScene("level1");
```

Here is the above code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brycecaine/9vesq0cw/10/) to demonstrate.

Also, the [Scenes](http://www.html5quintus.com/guide/scenes.md) page of the Quintus documentation has a section called "Inserting objects into a stage", which is somewhat related to the concept.

Hope that helps!